# How to log 500 status errors in console in express routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The typical errors I expect to see logged are not being logged in my express routes.
for example:

```
router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
  console.log(undefinedVariable)
})
```

I expect to get an error:

> ReferenceError: undefinedVarialbe is not defined;

however In the `router.get` I don't get any errors other than:

> GET / 500 3.641 ms - 478

in my console which is making debugging hard. Is there any way to get these errors to show in the console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the end of your routes, add this:

```
router.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  } else {
    console.log('404')
  }
});
```

This will catch all routes that were not handled by a handler before it, and all routes that resulted in an error.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I was being so silly, this was for a single page app so there was nothing to render. I had this in my app.js already if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    console.log(err)
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
} I just had to add the console.log in there, very silly of me but thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you used express-generator, there should already be an 'error handler' in app.js
Just add this to the bottom of that handler:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') console.log(err.stack);
```